# Intel Core i7-2670QM Overheating

Tags: laptop, cpu, temperature, intel-core-i7, overheating

Problem: I own an HP Pavilion dv7t-6b00 running the above processor. The TJ Max is set to 100°C, and it idles at around 66°C. I've tried applying two different types of thermal and have resorted to constant use of a Gigabyte cooling pad for any source of use.

Thoughts? Possible solutions? Ideas?

Anything?

Comment: 66C is not really overheating. Is there some particular reason you want the idle temperature lower?

Comment: Because when it is doing essentially anything, it will climb into the 80-90s range.

Comment: That seems pretty normal. The CPU will overclock itself if it's under load and has the room to do so. The CPU will do as much work as it can without overheating, so your CPU is probably just doing more work. Why do you think you need a cooling pad?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for overheating is the way the thermal compound is applied. Some people will apply it and spread it out flat and neat, the correct way is to apply multiple mounds on the cpu so that it will spread out and form a good seal when the heat sink is fastened down.